# If $|f(z)-w|<|w|/2$ how do you conclude $|f(z)|>|w|/2$? $z$ and non-zero $w$ are complex numbers.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> If $|f(z)-w|<|w|/2$ how do you conclude $|f(z)|>|w|/2$?

$z$ and non-zero $w$ are complex numbers. $f$ is a function of $z$. The inequality is defined on a domain $S$ in complex plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it using reverse triangle inequality. You have
$$\frac{|w|}{2} > |w - f(z)| \ge ||w| - |f(z)|| \ge |w| - |f(z)|,$$
which, when rearranged, implies
$$|f(z)| > |w| - \frac{|w|}{2} = \frac{|w|}{2}.$$
This works wherever the triangle inequality works, i.e. in real numbers, complex numbers, normed linear spaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because\begin{align}\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert&=\bigl\lvert f(z)-w+w\bigr\rvert\\&\geqslant\left\lvert\bigl\lvert f(z)-w)\bigr\rvert-w\right\rvert\\&=\lvert w\rvert-\bigl\lvert f(z)-w\bigr\rvert\\&>\dfrac{\lvert w\rvert}2.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the triangle inequality with $$\big||a|-|b|\big|\leq|a-b|.$$